# How to randomise video in html

Tags: html

Hello everyone i am trying to make a chrome extension but i am not really sure what to do! This is my code ( it is quite long) i am trying to do a randomisation when you click the icon and have video in it but i cant understand it as i have looked it up but is quite a specific question! Also i am new to html so if u spot a mistake then please tell me how to fix it because i wont know!

```
<html>

<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {
margin: 0px;
padding: opx;
font-family: Comic Sans MS;
font-size: 13px;
}

</style>
</head>
</body>

<body>


<button onclick="myFunction()">Try again</button>

<br id="demo"></br>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}

if x == 1) {
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="Clip 1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="Clip 1.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
}

if x == 2) {
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="Clip 2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="Clip 2.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
}

if x == 3) {
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="Clip 3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="Clip 3.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
}

if x == 4) {
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="Clip 4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="Clip 4.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
}

if x == 5) {
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="Clip 5.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="Clip 5.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
}

if x == 6) {
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="Clip 6.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="Clip 6.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
}
</script>

</body>
 </html>
```

Thanks for any replys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few errors and recomendations.

1. It is highly recommended to have your style in a separate external CSS file.
2. In your css, `padding` has a value of opx, this is a letter "o" not zero. Also when declaring zero, you need not specify units.
3. You have an ending `body` tag just below head which shouldn't be there.
4. `br` element shoul not have inner content. Try using another element, like `div`.
5. Instead of using several `if` blocks, I suggest using `switch`.
6. Your `if` conditions have one parenthesis missing `if (x == 6)`.
7. You need to handle the condition block. Writing plain html inside javascript will not write it into the html document.

i